# What is your workflow to coordinate Pivotal Tracker with Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial, workflow, dvcs, pivotaltracker

I want to use [Pivotal Tracker](http://www.pivotaltracker.com/) for a new project but I don't know how to use it with Mercurial to make it easy to go from one tool to the other.

What workflow do you use to link user stories/feature in Pivotal Tracker with your DVCS (Mercurial/Git)?

Thanks in advance for your advices.

Comment: Did you find or develop hooks for Mercurial and Pivot Tracker? I would be interested, if so.

Comment: Found this...didn't look at it in detail. http://gist.github.com/105261

Comment: Look nice! I will try if I can adapt this script for Pivotal Tracker. Thanks.

Comment: So, how did it turn out in the end. Did you make a Mercurial hook for PT?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If someone is still looking for an answer, there exists a service which allows mercurial users to connect to pivotal tracker using a syntax like `[#story_id finished]` in their commit messages. Bitbucket allows for this integration as well.

Links: https://bitbucket.org/proppy/hgpivotal/src/tip/hgpivotal.py

> [Note from Pivotal Tracker on the format](https://www.pivotaltracker.com/help/api?version=v5#Tracker_Updates_in_SCM_Post_Commit_Hooks):
>
> The minimum commit message string that will allow Tracker to associate
>   a source_commits POST with a story and create a comment is a single
>   story ID enclosed in square brackets: '[#12345678]'. A more typical
>   message, indicating that one commit completes two stories (which need
>   not be in the same Tracker project), might look like this: 'finally
>   [finished #12345678 #12345779], fixes client/server integration
>   glitch'
>
> If an included story was not already started (it was in the "not
>   started" state), an update to that story from /source_commits that
>   doesn't contain any other state-change information will automatically
>   start the story.
>
> To automatically finish a story by using a commit message, include
>   "fixed", "completed", or "finished" in the square brackets in addition
>   to the story ID. You may use different cases or forms of these verbs,
>   such as "Fix" or "FIXES", and they may appear before or after the
>   story ID. Note: For features, use of one of these keywords will put
>   the story in the finished state. For chores, it will put the story in
>   the accepted state.
>
> In some environments, code that is committed is automatically
>   deployed. For this situation, use the keyword "delivers" and feature
>   stories will be put in the delivered state.

Comment: Excellent! Much better than my post-commit hook. +1

Comment: Thanks for showing the syntax! Not even bitbucket mentions it exactly.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Post-Commit Hooks to link the two tools](http://www.pivotaltracker.com/help/api?version=v3#scm_post_commit):

> The Tracker API supports integration with post-commit hooks of Source Control Management (SCM) systems such as Subversion, Git, etc.
>   When a commit is made to the SCM, a trigger can call the Tracker API to add a story comment with the commit ID, author and message. It can also optionally change the story state.

Those hooks exists for Git, and should be written for Mercurial.

Comment: I can't find an existing hook for Mercurial to link with PT. I will have to do one myself...

Thanks for the hint!